# Окно авторизации через ВК не вмещается

Tags: yii2, вконтакте, oauth2

Использую виджет авторизации

```php
$authAuthChoice = AuthChoice::begin([
    'baseAuthUrl' => ['/user/security/auth'], 
    'popupMode' => true,
    'id' => $this->id,
]);
```

Однако при попытке авторизоваться окошко не вмещается в попап.

[image: окно разрешения доступа]

Как я понимаю, дело в ссылке, здесь [вместо](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites) `display=popup` указано `xoauth_displayname=$app->name`...

Вот: *oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=000000&response_type=code&redirect_uri=...&**xoauth_displayname=НАЗВАНИЕ_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ**&scope=email&state=...*

И это не из [воздуха](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/3bc0c8f52722abfb8b96a5f8defb80a59ea7f597/src/OAuth2.php#L71)

```php
public function buildAuthUrl(array $params = [])
    {
        $defaultParams = [
            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'redirect_uri' => $this->getReturnUrl(),
            'xoauth_displayname' => Yii::$app->name,
        ];
...
```

Подскажите, как передать дополнительный параметр `display=popup`/исправить существующий, чтобы ничего не поломать? Желательно из виджета.

Авторизация на dektrium/yii2-user.

Спасибо.

Comment: А стилями подрихтовать разве нельзя? Сделать окно больше или контент в окне меньше.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, нет, вроде можно указать ширину окна, но это не то. На контент вообще нельзя влиять, он же на oauth.vk.com.

Лучше тогда открывать на всю страницу)

Comment: Почему-то ведь используется "xoauth_displayname", возможно всё проще чем кажется, только я не нашёл решения..

Comment: Стилями можно подправить любой контент, который на твоей странице. Если в коде от vk стили прописаны атрибутами, то их можно удалить с помощью js. Но это уже самый последний вариант, потому что костыльный совсем.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, я упомянул, что контент на oauth.vk.com, он не на моей странице. Обновил скрин, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: Необходимо добавить параметр "display".

Comment: Все, я понял о каком окне речь. Наверно надо как-то скриптом задать параметры открываемого окна. Предполагаю надо перехватить событие открытия и задать дополнительные параметры.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, да, задать можно прямо в виджете, но это не то. Вот, [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites) сказано, как формировать ссылку. Вот вариант
[1](https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6074965&display=page&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback&scope=friends&response_type=code&v=5.101) и [2](https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6074965&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback&scope=friends&response_type=code&v=5.101) (нужен этот)